# Нужны книги по php

Tags: книги, mvc

Добрый вечер! Очень нужна информация по патернам и MVC!!Ещё нужна книга php 5 для профессионалов в полном варианте! Если есть, поделитесь пожалуйста))

Comment: это не является вопросом для тематики stackoverflow. ищите данную информацию в google.

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемый polk - все приходит с опытом! Если не **стоит** к изучению языка, книги не очень помогут, хотя возможно я не прав! Лучшая книга это http://php.su, обоснованы все основы - а MVC это уже ваш личный состав знаний и подход к программированию... Начните с Ютюба)